# File transfer in cordova

Tags: cordova, intel-xdk

> I am trying to download a file from remote server using cordova file transfer plugin in
>   Intel XDK. Here is my code

```
    var path ='/New_Directory/1.pdf'; 
    /*here New_Directory is my newly created directory by using  
    directoryEntry.getDirectory   */
    var uri = encodeURI("remote_location/file_name"); 
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();   
    fileTransfer.download(uri,path,
        function(entry) {
            alert("Success !!");            
        },
        function(error) {
           alert("Failed"); 
        },
        false
    );
```

but i am getting error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'isDirectory' of null
```

in VM191 FileTransfer.js:214.
How to solve this .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need file:// in your file path?